# session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent , but I didn't have any output before my session

Tags: session

Sorry for my poor English, 
I have an error when using session, it was okay when I create others pages with session, but I cannot solve this, please help.

> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /storage/ssd3/402/3124402/public_html/web/samplecode/sessiontest.php:1) in /storage/ssd3/402/3124402/public_html/web/samplecode/sessiontest.php on line 1

I only have the following in my php file, I don't have any html output.

```
<?php 
session_start();
?>
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Comment: look for a space before <?php

Comment: Thanks Tan, I have checked, there is no space before <?php